# Vim bypass re-do step

Tags: vim

I'm wondering if it is possible to bypass single re-do step in vim while traversing undo/redo history by <kbd>u</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>.

I know about wonderful vim's undo-tree but sometimes one just want to avoid single wrong/accidental change.

That is, for example, while doing some complex change and looking around for for context information is not so uncommon to accidentally hit some key, like `~` or (in Visual mode) `U` inadvertently.

In that cases, after noticing I broke something, I usually use undo to rapidly review recent changes I did so I find that mistake in place but I cannot fix it in place because, doing that, I would create new undo branch in which I couldn't reproduce below changes I previously *undowed* so I must hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> repeatedly until last change is replied and, then, manually find the mistake (which now I know what it is) to fix it.

If there were simply a way to "jump" single <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to avoid that wrong change being replayed, the whole process would become much more faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. That "feature" would require that Vim internally stores the undo / redo as a List of commands to be applied to the text (and what would you do with file reloads of external changes, or with (custom) commands that are not idempotent?).

However, there's a workflow that allows the editing and replay of a chain of commands: **macros**. If you record your actions in a macro (e.g. `qq`), you can then stop recording, and edit the register (on the command line: `:let @q = '<C-r>q'`, or by pasting into a scratch buffer, editing, and then yanking again). Then, replay as many times as required.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it.
Regarding your workaround, If I understood it well, it requires to start recording before knowing I will commit a mistake, which seems a bit awkward to me.
But it arises to me another (maybe possible) approach: If we could take a shoot between two redo steps, it should be possible to generate a diff between them and apply it as a patch.
BTW, the answer to my original question is "no" (thanks). But I will keep in mind these thoughts. Maybe I can make a try later...